# strlen doesn't work even with #include <string.h> in C

Tags: c, strlen, string.h

Does it not return an int or something?
This is a snippet of my code:

```
int wordlength(char *x);

int main()
{
    char word;
    printf("Enter a word: \n");
    scanf("%c \n", &word);
    printf("Word Length: %d", wordlength(word));
    return 0;
}

int wordlength(char *x)
{
    int length = strlen(x);
    return length;
}
```

Comment: A `char` is not a string...

Comment: but I read that strlen wants a char as an argument. So, wordlength wants a char of x. When the user puts in a word, it'll be considered as a char. Also, my professor told us to put <string.h> when using strlen.

Comment: @Evyione: no, `strlen` needs a `char *` (actually a `const char *`), not just a `char`.

Comment: You might want to read the [tag:string] [tag-wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/string/info).

Comment: "I read that strlen wants a char as an argument" -- No, you did not read that ... and it doesn't make sense. "So, wordlength wants a char of x" -- No, it wants a pointer to char ... which is what you gave it, but the point is that `word` is only 1 char long. You need to make it an array of chars, big enough to hold any word you expect to read.

Answer (score 1):

Change this part:

```
char word;
printf("Enter a word: \n");
scanf("%c \n", &word);
```

to:

```
char word[256];       // you need a string here, not just a single character
printf("Enter a word: \n");
scanf("%255s", word); // to read a string with scanf you need %s, not %c.
                      // Note also that you don't need an & for a string,
                      // and note that %255s prevents buffer overflow if
                      // the input string is too long.
```

You should also know that the compiler would have helped you with most of these problems if you had enabled warnings (e.g. `gcc -Wall ...`)

---

Update: For a sentence (i.e. a string including white space) you would need to use [fgets](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets):

```
char sentence[256];
printf("Enter a sentence: \n");
fgets(sentence, sizeof(sentence), stdin);
```

Comment: I tried putting a sentence, and it doesn't count whitespace?

Comment: That's correct - the code above accepts a "word", as implied by your buffer name. For a sentence you would need to use `fgets` (see edit above).

Answer (score 1):

Function `strlen` is applied to strings (character arrays) that have the terminating zero. You are applying the function to a pointer to a single character. So the program has undefined behaviour.